# Magento1.9: How to reinstall magento engine without reuploading files?

Tags: magento-1.9, installation

I had installed Magento in local server. There is some problem with it.

Now I want to reinstall the Magento engine and database as well from scratch. More specifically I want to access the installation page where I can start again, being on the existing system.

Comment: remove the local.xml file which is located in app/etc/ directory and hit the url

Comment: it says, 'database connection error'. :-(

Comment: Did you double check you database name to be sure, as normally it shows 'magento' by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone may need this (reinstalling magento engine) in some cases like trying to install template and sample data.

So in that case of reinstalling Magento engine and the database from scratch, follow this steps:

• Go to your **database**(for your magento project) through phpMyAdmin or other one and **drop the tables**. If you can not drop some tables, just empty those tables.

• Then go to your Magento project root and delete `local.xml` file located in `app/etc` folder.

• Now you should be able to see the primary installation page where you can start the installation procedure.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

1. Login to database at phpmyadmin.
2. empty particular database or drop all tables.
3. Goto app->etc folder and remove local.xml file.
4. Start installation by run your url.